# WSL connection to database by R-Shiny

Tags: r, sql-server, ubuntu, shiny, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working with Shiny Server. I got installed subsystem for Windows WSL (Ubuntu) where I installed Shiny Server. I am wondering how can I set up connection to SQL Server/Access database and then run an app with database data. Should connection code be included inside script or somewhere else?

Comment: Frankly, I've always had problems with R accessing Access databases, either due to bitness (64-bit R and 32-bit Office) or some other problems. If you need "database-like" storage, I'd recommend SQLite or an upcomer, DuckDB.

Comment: However, to address your question, in a shiny app, DB-connection code can either go a global namespace (either outside the `server` function component or in `globals.R`) for a single server, or perhaps *within* the `server` component for per-client connection management. Some good refs: https://db.rstudio.com/, https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html, https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/236020708-Strategies-for-connecting-Shiny-applications-to-databases

Comment: I am not struggling about connection locally (connection in R script). Issue is connection via WSL could arise difficulties ?? If yes what ways we got to workaround this issue...

Comment: Are you accessing SQL Server or MS Access files? Have you tried something yet? In my experience, using R in WSL was able to access an external database the same exact way as the same code in R in windows.

Comment: Thank you. No it's just theoretical question. I tried apps run only locally not via WSL. I just looked for experienced person in this domain. If all logic is similar to run scripts like in Windows this answer is fine for me.

Comment: You need linux-odbc-drivers, linux-odbc-configuration (I'm assuming `DBI`/`odbc`), and WSL that can see the same network as windows. Other than that, to me it's been all the same.